# Active Choice Parameters are not available in env when using Execute Shell as a build step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using Active Choice Parameters successfully to define parameters with options that change dynamically, reacting to other parameters values, with custom HTML etc.

Unfortunately, the values of these parameters are not available at job builds as env-vars, while regular parameters do.

If I print `env` within the Execute Shell build step, I see all regular parameters and their values, but not the "active" ones.

How can I make these active parameters so that they would be available as environment variables in a shell execution?

I'm using Jenkins v2.278

Comment: Can you show how you access the variable and the section of the plugin?

Comment: I print `env` in the Execute Shell step and all regular parameters are there but "active" ones aren't

Comment: This is very hard to track down without you providing the code of your print and the active choice parameters

Comment: Found it: when composing custom HTML, in order for the value to be passed to the builds, the input must contain the following attribute: `name="value"`

Answer (score 0):

When using Active Parameters with custom HTML inputs, in order for the value to be passed to the builds, the input must contain the following HTML attribute: `name="value"`, e.g. `<input name="value" />`